# Swift 3- How to override a method in subclass

Tags: ios, swift, overriding, subclass, swift3

In Swift 3, I want to override **caretRectForPosition** method of `UITextField` in its subclass say `CustomTextField`

Here is my code which is working fine prior to Swift 2.3

```
import UIKit

class CustomTextField: UITextField {
    override func caretRectForPosition(position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect.zero
    }
}
```

but in Swift 3 its showing a compile time error Method does not override any method from its superclass.

Can any one help me out on this.

I am using this code to hide the cursor of text field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably the method name changed in Swift 3. Did you lookup the current documentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Swift 3 `caretRectForPosition(position:)` is changed to `caretRect(for:)`.

```
override func caretRect(for position: UITextPosition) -> CGRect {
    return CGRect.zero
}
```

Check [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextinput/1614518-caretrect) for more detail on `UITextInput`.

Comment: Yes I just found this.. anyways thanks for your time. take +1 from me